# Setting lastUpdated of a Grails domain object in Spock

Tags: grails, spock, grails-2.2

I have a Grails 2.2.4 project, and I'm trying to write a unit test for a method that queries over `lastUpdated`, like so:

```
Tile.createCriteria().list {
  lt('lastUpdated', new Date() - 1)
}
```

This method works fine in real life, but fails in my unit tests because I can't create any test data with `lastUpdated` other than `now`.  Setting `myTile.lastUpdated` explicitly doesn't work, since that's an update and thus triggers the auto-timestamping.  Turning off auto timestamping requires the `eventTriggeringInterceptor`, which doesn't seem to be available in unit tests.  Mocking the default `Date` constructor to return other values was also no help.  Direct SQL updates are not available in unit tests at all.

Is this possible in unit tests at all, or do I have to write an integration test?

Comment: Personally, I think if you're testing persistence, you should always favour an integration test, unless you've a very good reason not to. Running your persistence tests against a mock in-memory GORM implementation is just asking for trouble.

Comment: That's fair, but I don't really want to test persistence, I want to test my query (which really is just about that simple).

Answer (score 1):

It's interesting that you say mocking the default date constructor to return other values is no help. I successfully do that quite often when I have queries such as yours that new up a date.
For your situation, I would have a unit test that looked something like this:

```
def 'test lastUpdated query'() {
    setup:
    Title lessThan = new Title(lastUpdated:new Date(1477152000000)) //22 Oct 2016 16:00 UTC, should be found
    Title equalTo = new Title(lastUpdated:new Date(1477238400000)) //24 Oct 2016 16:00 UTC, should not find, not less than 1 day before, but equal to 1 day before
    Title notLessThan = new Title(lastUpdated:new Date(1477296000000)) //24 Oct 2016 08:00 UTC, should not find, not less than 1 day before
    Date date = new Date(1477324800000) //24 Oct 2016 16:00 UTC
    Date.metaClass.constructor = {-> return date}

    when:
    List<Title> result = service.someMethod()

    then:
    result.size() == 1
    result.contains(lessThan)
    !result.contains(equalTo)
    !result.contains(notLessThan)
}
```